# How to implement IdentityServer4 SSO based on password flow?

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I have two web app:

1. webApp1 in domain1
   (Spa1 -> WebApi1 -> IdentityServer4 -> db1)
2. webApp2 in domain2
   (Spa2 -> WebApi2 -> db2)

User story:

1. End-User John already authorized by password flow in IdentityServer4 located under WebApi1, so Spa1 have the JWT with "WebApi1" scope and refresh 
   token as well.
2. John in Spa1 clicks the button "Go to Spa2" then he is rederected to Spa2.
3. In John’s browser, a new page is opened with Spa2, and John sees that he is already authenticated by IdentityServer4 in Spa2 
   and authorized for WebApi2 (John can use Spa2 functionality without additional login dialog), becouse db2 has a mapping db1.users->db2.users (so webApp2 can use it's own roles).

This is similar to the scenario when a user read a mail in gmail spa and from a letter follows the link to youtube (without additional auth actions)
and sees that he is already authenticated by google.

I wonted to use authorization code flow with config

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "app1,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret1".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = { "api1"},
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
},

new Client {
    ClientId = "app2",
    ClientSecrets = 
    {
        new Secret("secret2".Sha256())
    },
    Enabled = true,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code, 
    RequireConsent = false,
    AllowRememberConsent = false,
    RedirectUris =
        new List<string> {
            "http://localhost:5436/account/oAuth2"
        },

    AllowedScopes = { "api2" },
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt
}
```

, but it requires additional authentication through the browser 
*which is needless process* since the user already authenticated.

How should i implement this auth scenario in IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

1. Create a custom code authority which issue auth code for app1 and redirect it to app2.
2. Create extension grant implementation which authenticate a user by code.

Let's first see how it works:

1. Authorize the user (i used postman).

Request:

```js
POST /connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:5000
grant_type=password&client_id=app1&client_secret=app1secret&scope=offline_access%20app1.api%20auth.api&username=tu1&password=111111
```

Response:

```js
{"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE0MDExYjViNGM0ZGYxYTUzZWFhMzhiMjBiZWVlOGM5IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTcwODE1OTYsImV4cCI6MTU1NzA4NTE5NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJhcHAxLmFwaSIsImF1dGguYXBpIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFwcDEiLCJzdWIiOiJ0dTEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NTcwODE1OTYsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiYXBwMS5hcGkiLCJhdXRoLmFwaSIsIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIl0sImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.bV1lvPs8AFUq7kcCAEMz4rS2vOmUIzrogN3EByQViBkKNFF6ijrizVc2GxiXRNTwl35Kgsb7beoFaVy4Ai2RmyMxmyJumwiwR0-wbX_mrs-XcfADfhEdLQJWLvAkbm2jm3FvDC-7F6S5Mip-QtbcXdgqg5oQo53nBJDXc7bsn1MaKPkivR1tg9CjA0uOQC891aBr4BzRZeH43YpVjxO7zzYL9vcplIL79nkhiG4iVfo7Ti8JJa4Q7HzH6lj0V_NrTY3BRzvCHVPNy0cFtfFTE1l_abMel1ftozyvFtrsTgVqRZhFfzY0d_7K8M9wtXAa7vbYW7oAhvnxVlga4HX_zg",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": "26df6326251b7590cf6eb9898967e814ff291712aa7504ac84f9d8ae07374d3c"}
```

Good! We got the token with payload:

```js
{
  "nbf": 1557072351,
  "exp": 1557075951,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": [
    "http://localhost:5000/resources",
    "app1.api",
    "auth.api"
  ],
  "client_id": "app1",
  "sub": "tu1",
  "auth_time": 1557072351,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "app1.api",
    "auth.api", //!!! 
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

The token has the scope “auth.api” - it means we can request the code.

2. Request the redirection to WebApp2 with code and state.

Request:

```
GET /api/CodeAuthority?state=random_base64_value_generated_in_spa1_at_the_begining
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE0MDExYjViNGM0ZGYxYTUzZWFhMzhiMjBiZWVlOGM5IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTcwODE1OTYsImV4cCI6MTU1NzA4NTE5NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJhcHAxLmFwaSIsImF1dGguYXBpIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFwcDEiLCJzdWIiOiJ0dTEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NTcwODE1OTYsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiYXBwMS5hcGkiLCJhdXRoLmFwaSIsIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIl0sImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.bV1lvPs8AFUq7kcCAEMz4rS2vOmUIzrogN3EByQViBkKNFF6ijrizVc2GxiXRNTwl35Kgsb7beoFaVy4Ai2RmyMxmyJumwiwR0-wbX_mrs-XcfADfhEdLQJWLvAkbm2jm3FvDC-7F6S5Mip-QtbcXdgqg5oQo53nBJDXc7bsn1MaKPkivR1tg9CjA0uOQC891aBr4BzRZeH43YpVjxO7zzYL9vcplIL79nkhiG4iVfo7Ti8JJa4Q7HzH6lj0V_NrTY3BRzvCHVPNy0cFtfFTE1l_abMel1ftozyvFtrsTgVqRZhFfzY0d_7K8M9wtXAa7vbYW7oAhvnxVlga4HX_zg
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8bec320a-0cc9-4aeb-aba1-acdbd89384cf
Host: localhost:5000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302
status: 302
Date: Sun, 05 May 2019 19:16:44 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://WebApp2.test.url?code=random_base64_value_generated_in_is4_api&state=random_base64_value_generated_in_spa1_at_the_begining
```

Note, we put the token from the first step to this get request and we has been redirected to “http://WebApp2.test.url?code=random_base64_value_generated_in_is4_api&state=random_base64_value_generated_in_spa1_at_the_begining”.

3. So, now the user can be authenticated from WebApp2 by code and state.

Request:

```
POST /connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4adc90e8-ae6a-421b-8514-8b96e0f7108a
Host: localhost:5000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 197
Connection: keep-alive
grant_type=app2_auth_code&code=random_base64_value_generated_in_is4_api&client_id=app2&client_secret=app2secret&scope=code.authentication&state=random_base64_value_generated_in_spa1_at_the_begining
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
status: 200
Date: Sun, 05 May 2019 19:25:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE0MDExYjViNGM0ZGYxYTUzZWFhMzhiMjBiZWVlOGM5IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTcwODQzNDEsImV4cCI6MTU1NzA4Nzk0MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJjb2RlLmF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImFwcDIiLCJzdWIiOiJ0dTEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NTcwODQzNDEsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiY29kZS5hdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiJdLCJhbXIiOlsiYXBwMl9hdXRoX2NvZGUiXX0.bDonw4SjGGqgwxnJeJoBP4-DfjWcAXUsXrvBx5Qav3cS329g9qciXzBcEpFmNB41De3GW-ocVFb8AFgGGCTENW3B2lL9HdopJ9C2ksPRwB1qTJ9S98HZZjOT0wQ2N-AbfQWAJlH12qGeml2UjB-L-afFAPVM-KpOh4my9znvUJWV_L_7q2Lwpv23fSkyGDahQCcZVLcurCjx8uQp1xliOF7b6qZ87kwh5brxGvUXP3oWjfmBvG_PsAFvGHZwgicjTWK7ED_OGTULCvtCtNO5RwW9_HINIl-217KnYgsrHNfaFCiv03vKXckvmkzfacreO0FaDr3r0nS2dMGrkyZ2sA","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

We just exchanged the code and state for the token:

```
{
  "nbf": 1557073472,
  "exp": 1557077072,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": [
    "http://localhost:5000/resources",
    "code.authentication"
  ],
  "client_id": "app2",
  "sub": "tu1",     //!!!
  "auth_time": 1557073472,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "code.authentication" //!!!
  ],
  "amr": [
    "app2_auth_code"
  ]
}
```

Now the WebApp2 knows who(sub) initiated the redirect.

The code ([Solution on github](https://github.com/case651/CustomCodeAuthIS4)):

IdentityServer4:

```
namespace TestIdentityServer4
{
    public class Startup
    { 
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(new List<ApiResource>()
                {
                    //Api which returns redirect url with code and state.
                    new ApiResource("auth.api", "Auth API"),
                    //App1 api. Just to show that app1 has some functionality (IdentityController).
                    new ApiResource("app1.api", "App1 API"),
                    //This resource is authentification functionality implemented by AuthCodeValidator.
                    new ApiResource("code.authentication", "Authentication by code")
                })
                .AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>()
                {
                    //web app1
                    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "app1",
                        ClientSecrets =
                        {
                            new Secret("app1secret".Sha256())
                        },
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                        AllowedScopes =
                        {
                            "app1.api",
                            "auth.api"
                        },
                        AllowOfflineAccess = true
                    },
                    //web app2
                    new Client
                    {

                        ClientId = "app2",
                        ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                        {
                            new Secret("app2secret".Sha256())
                        },

                        AllowedGrantTypes = { "app2_auth_code" },

                        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                        {
                            "code.authentication"
                        }
                    }
                })
                //App1 users for test purpose
                .AddTestUsers( new List<TestUser>()
                {
                    new TestUser()
                    {
                        Username = "tu1",
                        Password = "111111",
                        SubjectId = "tu1"
                    }
                })
                //Regestring of the custom validator
                .AddExtensionGrantValidator<AuthCodeValidator>();

            //Our IS4 has the custom api (CodeAuthorityController). It is also a resorce that should be protected.
            //It should be awailable fore user authorized in app1.
            services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
                    opt =>
                    {
                        opt.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                        opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        opt.ApiName = "auth.api";
                    });

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Code authority:

```
namespace TestIdentityServer4.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class CodeAuthorityController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                string state = this.Request.Query["state"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
                    return StatusCode(500);

                var code = GenerateCode();

                SaveCodeAndState(code, state);

                return Redirect($"http://WebApp2.test.url?code={code}&state={state}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log e
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }

        private string GenerateCode()
        {
            //CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(16)
            return "random_base64_value_generated_in_is4_api";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save the code hash and state hash to storage 
        /// </summary>
        private void SaveCodeAndState(string code, string state)
        {
            //Save the code request ({requestId, app1SessionId, hash(code), hash(state), expTime}) to storage with exp time
            //db.SaveCodeRequest(code.Sha256(), state.Sha256())
        }
    }
}
```

Code validator:

```
namespace TestIdentityServer4.Validators
{
    public class AuthCodeValidator : IExtensionGrantValidator
    {
        public string GrantType => "app2_auth_code";

        public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
        {
            var code = context.Request.Raw.Get("code");
            var state = context.Request.Raw.Get("state");

            var sub = GetSubByCode(code, state);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sub))
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
                return;
            }

            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(sub, GrantType);
            return;
        }

        //Check the code and the state (and the request are still active) and returns sub
        private string GetSubByCode(string code, string state)
        {
            return "tu1";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work for you because you have your login flows implemented via `ResourceOwnerCredentials` grant type, which means when user John accesses spa1, spa1 logs user John through a custom login flow.

In order for this to work out of the box, easiest way and most recommended approach would probably be to convert spa1 to use one of the preferred grant types (like `Implicit` or `AuthorizationCode` for example) and then once user John logs in through the central login page served by your IdentityServer 4, it would leave cookies and then any subsequent token request attempts would log user in directly and issue the requested tokens to the appropriate client apps (can also skip consent optionally as you have done in your example).

There is one other way that I can think of, which I would not recommend for you, but I have personally implemented it once due to specific client requirements to retain the `ResourceOwnerCredentials` grant type and custom login page, but still achieve single sign on behaviour. If both, your spa1 and IdentityServer4, are hosted on the same domain (so `spa1.yourdomain.com` and `auth.yourdomain.com`) and your user store (usernames and credentials) are shared between your IdentityServer4 and spa1 you could technically upon the user entering credentials in your spa1 login page, programatically submit the `POST` request to identity server 4 login page with the form details containing user credentials, get the cookie out of the response and then store the cookie in the user's client. Whenever your user John would try to access spa2, the redirect to IdentityServer4 would still happen, but the whole login flow would be circumvented because there would already be a cookie to automatically log the user in. If you do decide to implement something along these lines, please make sure to research security concerns (there will be plenty) and really evaluate if that's required.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need seamless authentication, which will also work for mobile applications. Did you consider Extension Grant? Is it possible to create some version of authorization_code validator which will additionaly receive app1 token and will not redirect to login page?

Comment: @pokercase yeah i considered extension grants, but then if user john accesses spa2 on its own, he won’t be able to log in because it won’t have token. Also my spa2 needed different scopes and also when token expires on spa2 it won’t be able to silently refresh. And also transferring state of the token between spas sounds like an annoying thing to maintain.